# How validate string,int, datetime

Tags: c#

Help me make clean code. I need to do an action where I can pass a list of fields for validation. In my method I will input `string`, `int`, `DataTime` and display the name of the field where the error is contained. It can be done with many but I want best practices.

I wrote this

```
public override object Call()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.MinValue;
    var validateArguments = ValidateArguments(now);

    return validateArguments;
}

private static bool ValidateArguments(params object[] args)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {

        if (args[i] == null|| Convert.ToDateTime(args[i])==DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
            // Get the method that called us
            MethodBase info = trace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();

            // Get information on the parameter that is null so we can add its name to the exception
            ParameterInfo param = info.GetParameters()[i];

            InfoManager.MessageBox("Error in {0}", param.Name);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

But this code produces following error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

How do I fix it or write other clean code?

Comment: Create a class with your parameters and validate them. Dont use `object[]`

Comment: `Call()` has no parameters, so you get here: `info.GetParameters()` an empty array , therefore you get the exception. What exactly do you try in this line? I don't understand it fully

Comment: That "return true" is in the wrong position: when the first parameter validates, the method returns (and skips the rest)

Comment: If you want to validate "string, int and DateTime", how do you know which it should be? Would you catch `"10"` (a string) that should have been `10` (an int)?

Comment: the logic is this. I get value in call () and then i need checked it for empty (0, null,datetime.minvalue) if they are not filled then I need to display them.

Answer (score 0):

On this line `ParameterInfo param = info.GetParameters()[i];` you are getting the parameters of your method `Call()` which has no parameters, and then indexing it with `[i]`, this leads to an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Perhaps you want to do this `ParameterInfo param = info.GetParameters()` and check that it is longer than 0 like this `if (param.Length > 0)`. I cannot tell you what to do because I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Best of luck!

Comment: the call() has no parameters and I get a lot of value in the method. they are calculated there and must pass validation (0, null,datetime.minvalue). what needs to be done to pass validation?